# Type mismatch for Application.Average when there is text

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of data in column A. Some is text, some is numbers. Application.Average yields a type mismatch because of the text. What is the best way to get around this? I could write all the numeric values to an array then average the array, but that seems like a pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If col **A** has a mixture of numbers and text the following should not generate an error:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("A:A")
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(R)
End Sub
```

unless there is an error in one of the cells.